# How can I run a whois on an IP address?

Tags: command-line, whois

So I'm looking at my sent traffic in `iftop` and I'm connected to an IP I don't recognise and I'm sending quite a bit of traffic their way. I'd like to work out where in the world this IP goes to.

Online I've been running whois queries against IP addresses for a long time but I don't think I've ever been able to get it to work for IP addresses. Is there some trick to making the `whois` command handle IPs too?

Here's what I'm doing:

```
oli@bert:~$ whois 224.0.0.251
No whois server is known for this kind of object.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### `224.0.0.251` is a multicast address for mDNS

This is my computer broadcasting to the local network via a [multicast address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_address).

The address is reserved so whois doesn't know what on earth to do with it. Perhaps they should improve the error message for muppets like me :o)